# converting to string return null

Tags: c#, console-application

while am trying to convert the return value of add method to string it is not returning any value in console.while i remove the tostring method it is returning value.if i write any character inside the double quote it is showing in console.
what is happening while am calling tostring method?
if i didn't put any double quote as parameter it is showing compile time error like (specify culture of string)
what is the purpose of specifying culture while converting int to string?
i think i can convert integer value to string by calling tostring method,why can't i do conversion in this scenario?

```
        private static int Add(int x,int y)
        {
            return x+y;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Add(23,54).ToString(""));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

thanks.

Comment: This code is working ... with or without ""

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about implementation;

From [`Int32.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wch342y(v=vs.110).aspx)

> If format is null **or an empty string ("")**, the return value of this
>   instance is formatted with the general numeric format specifier ("G").

That's why `.ToString("")` is equal to `.ToString()` because

From [`Int32.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The ToString() method formats an Int32 value in the default ("G", or
>   general) format by using the NumberFormatInfo object of the current
>   culture.

I tried all cultures to format with `.ToString("")` and **no culture** returns `null` or empty string.

```
foreach (var c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    if((77).ToString("G", c) != "77")
        Console.WriteLine (c.Name);
}
```

Blue line probably there is a plugin (maybe ReSharper) that warn you to use another overloads that takes `CultureInfo` as a parameter for example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ToString` with no parameters

```
Add(23,54).ToString()
```

Using the parameter you specified you set a culture for the string conversion.
More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: if i didn't put any double quote it is showing compile time error like (specify culture of string) what is the purpose of specifying culture while converting int to string? Read the question.

Comment: My guess is the guy didn't want anything to do with culuture, but since he used it I thought an explanation would be nice. This code compiles without the double quote.

Comment: @mot yes it is working but there occuring a blue line under tostring that line is because,i didn't specified the culture of string.if i put a ("") it's not showing error but nothing i can see in the console/

Comment: That blue line probably comes as a warning from resharper. You can read about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22887804/why-specify-culture-in-string-conversion

Answer (score 0):

simply specify your culture of string as string.empty

```
            Console.WriteLine(Add(23,54).ToString(string.Empty));
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Culture Name:"" (empty string)

Culture Identifier:0x007F

Language-Country/Region:invariant culture

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

[string.Empty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx) is a read-only field whereas "" is a compile time constant.some Places they behave differently.

Comment: What? o.O There is no difference to use `""` and `string.Empty` here. _Even_ if could, `string.Empty` wasn't specify any culture to using only itself.

Comment: @SonerGönül i saw this article from msdn.string.Empty is a read-only field whereas "" is a compile time constant